# OpenJDK 8 Compilation using C++17

Tags: c++, cygwin

OpenJDK 8 by standard compiles(makefile) with c++98. Is it possible to compile using C++17?.

- I tried changing `-std=gnu++98` to `-std=gnu++17` in flags.m4, but it had no effect.
- Also I tried setting flag `--with-extra-cxxflags='-std=gnu++17'` to configure and it also had no effect.
- Compilation also occurs using C++98. To compile I use cygwin, which uses compiler from VS 2013. OS - Windows.

Comment: The Standard selecting flags are usually of the form `-std=gnu++98` and `-std=gnu++17`. Is this a typo in the question or does OpenJDK require different flags?  Also if you don't require compiler specific extensions then prefer `-std=c++17` etc.

Comment: I apologize, yes, that's a typo

Comment: By no effect, what do you mean? Did it still compile? Did it still compile but you could tell by the build output it was still compiling for `98? Were you unable to tell which Standard revision was used? Was the no effect that the computer sat there and did nothing?

Comment: I said jdk also compiles to 98, because it doesn't understand what constexpr is. It feels like something else needs to be changed in make, but I didn't find it.

Comment: The problem is that VS 2013 uses a compiler that does not support changing the standard. Versions of VS earlier than 2013 are not supported by OpenJDK 8.